# TwiML response body too large Error 11750 laravel

Tags: php, laravel, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
use Twilio\TwiML\VoiceResponse;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
// call process
    public function welcome(Request $request)
    {
        $twiml = new VoiceResponse();
        if(isset($request->Digits)){
            switch($request->Digits){
                case 1:
                    $twiml->say('thank you calling us');
                    break;
                default:
                    $twiml->say('You have entered wrong key');
                    break;
            }
        } else{
            $twiml->say(
                'Thank you for calling Call Congress! Press 1 for Connect the call.'
            )->gather([
                'numDigits' => 1,
                'action' => $this->endCall();
            ]);
            /*$gather = $twiml->gather(array('numDigits' => 1));
            $gather->say('Thank you for calling us. Press 1 to continue the call.');*/
        }

        return $twiml;
    }

    public static function endCall()
    {
        $twiml = new Twiml();

        $twiml->say(
            'Thank you for using Call Congress! ' .
            'Your voice makes a difference. Goodbye.'
        )->hangup();

        return $twiml;
    }
}
```

I am getting an error that 'In your response to Twilio's request, the response body is larger than 64 kB.
'. Possible Causes  The TwiML that you are serving is larger than 64 kB or You are serving non-TwiML content in your response. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use a browser or Postman and hit your endpoint. What do you see as the response?

Comment: I have hit in browser and postman both. But it working properly in browser. For more details you can check the screenshot url (https://prnt.sc/rz2q5u).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually this means your application is crashing and returning a stack trace to Twilio to execute, resulting in this error.

Comment: Hello Alan. 
Thanks for your supports. 
But this application is working properly in my browser. When i call to twilio number then it give me error in twilio debugger. 
When i run it in browser then it works properly. For more details you can find the attached screen url(https://prnt.sc/rz2q5u).

Comment: Twilio by default uses the POST method. Your browser only uses a GET. You an tell Twilio to use a GET or as Alex mentioned, download Postman and test your application using a POST.

Comment: Thanks It's working now. 
I was using get method now i have convert it into post method and now it's working. 
Thanks again.